# How different is Demo world from a regular world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I downloaded the Minecraft demo and started working, after the free 100 minutes, I bought the game and keep on playing that demo world.

Now, after 10h I've found that Demo world is always the same but I don't know how different it is from a regular "new game in singleplayer" world.

Should I start a new game using a random generated world or am I going to find the same elements than in the demo world?.

I recently found redstone and some diamonds, have sheep and some crops... so if I start a new game it's going to be a pain, but it'll be worse if I wait another 10h more...

Comment: What do you mean by "always the same"? Your last paragraph seems to indicate that you have encountered at least some variety.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The demo version of Minecraft generates a world with a fixed seed (according to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Demo_mode); that seed is -343522682.

Beyond that, and the demo's time restrictions, it functions as any other world would generated from that seed. The landscape and player spawn will always be the same.

If you like the world you've built from the demo seed, you can continue to play in it. You should not be missing any features or anything like that.